# How to change the PCL profile in Xamarin.Forms (Portable) Application

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I just wanted to know about, how to change the PCL profile in Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.
While installing some of the package, I am getting an error that, this package is not compatible with the PCL profile 259.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/#Editing_PCL_Settings

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html) tells about all the PCL profiles as of VS2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on the PCL project and select Properties. Then, in the "Library" tab, select the "Change..." button under the Targeting section.

Select the targets you want which match the profile you want.

[image]

Comment: @ChandreshKhambhayata A word of warning, you will most likely have to uninstall all NuGet packages before changing profiles. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37714888/3850012) you might only need to uninstall the Xamarin Forms library but I have not tried that before myself.

Comment: Is there a way to change the target manually? I want to target `Profile44` I tried editing the project file but that didn't do the job.

Comment: this is no longer working solution with VS2017, when you click change, there is no option to remove Wp Silverlight 8 although it is selected.

Comment: @Shimmy you need to amend packages.config file also

Comment: For VS 2017 Community I did r-click the PCL > Properties > Application > Target Framework.

Comment: For Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac (v. 7.5.2, build 40): right-click on the PCL project in the solution explorer (pane on the left with the list of projects, folders and files) -> Options -> Under "Build" click "General" -> in the top section "Target Framework" click on "Change..." button next to ".NET Portable"